# Pass a simple string when opening a child window

Tags: javascript

In the parent window:

```
window.open('page.php','nameIWant','toolbar=no')
```

How do I get the target specified in window.open() from the new window code.

I tried to retrieve document.title, document.name and document.target, none gave me 'nameIWant'
or is there a simple way to get a string upon opening, that works in IE8.

Comment: Just curious... why do you need to know `"nameIWant"` when you already know it's `"nameIWant"`?

Comment: Oh cause my child window needs a dynamic string upon opening.. there maybe many child windows using the same code. I just needed something to anchor my php on (anchor! sounds like a bad HTML pun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't name the document, you name the new window. Try `window.name` in the newly opened window.

Comment: the website makes me wait 7 minutes Mr Impatient ;)

Answer (score 1):

getting the `document` object of the child window is simply referencing the newly opened window and get the `document` object from it:

http://jsfiddle.net/3pQk6/

```
var child = window.open();

//set title
child.document.title = 'foo'

//text node in child window's body
child.document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('bar'));​​​
```

Comment: that's interesting, i guess it allows me to js and php inject names into my child window after the fact.